# DEPRECATION: The default behavior of shouldReloadAll will change in Ember Data 2.0 to always return false when there is at least one

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

At the moment of this question i'm running the latest Ember and Ember Data versions.

[image]

I'm working with the DS.RESTAdapter calling for a `/places` this way:

```js
this.store.findAll('place');
```

The model only have a name attribute `name: DS.attr('string')`
The JSON is the following:

```
{
  places: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "San Francisco"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Havana"
    }
  ]
}
```

I made the template and with the corresponding `each` and everything shows up and works so far but i get a deprecation warnings that tells the following:

> DEPRECATION: The default behavior of shouldReloadAll will change in
>   Ember Data 2.0 to always return false when there is at least one
>   "destination" record in the store. If you would like to preserve the
>   current behavior please override shouldReloadAll in your
>   adapter:application and return true.

I don't know exactly what's the best approach to solve this warning. I'm new to ember so any further explanation will be fine.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stuck on the same spot here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `shouldReloadAll() { return true; }` in your application adapter and the warning goes away and the current default behavior is the same.

Comment: Or return `false` if you want Ember Data 2.0 behaviour ( + remove the function after updating to v. 2.0).

Comment: @jacob Just returning false doesn't work. As the deprecation states that it will return false if there is at least 1 record. So you really need to check to see if any records are loaded before returning false.

Comment: can we get an explanation of what this actually does? What are the implications of changing it?

Comment: @GraemeStuart http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_shouldReloadAll It allows you to tell Ember when the records should be fetched from the server. This is particularly useful when applied to model-specific adapters; if you know some data almost never changes on the server, you can make the adapter for that model check the cache first before fetching from the API.

Comment: Could you show this in a little more context? I'm trying to understand _where_ to put this function.

Comment: @Eric Wilson check my answer.

Answer (score 5):

To comply with the new default behavior, override `shouldReloadAll` like this:

```js
function shouldReloadAll( store, snapshot ) {
    return !store.peekAll( snapshot.type.modelName ).length
}
```

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo This is just fancy logic for returning a boolean if there is currently no data in the store for the given model type.  If the length of peekAll is positive it will be true, or false otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

To answer @Eric Wilson question:

> I will award the bounty to an answer that contains the necessary
>   details to override the shouldReloadAll function. In other words, I
>   can't figure out what to do with these snippets of code.

First use:

```
ember g adapter application
```

Then go to newly-generated `app/adapters/application.js` and replace code with:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  shouldReloadAll() {
    return true;
  }
});
```

You're done. [Demo on Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c704a29f20756013cc5f?openFiles=adapters.application.js%2Capplication.template.hbs).

Returning `true` from `shouldReloadAll` function basically instructs Ember to re-fetch models each time you call `findAll` method and fire request to your backend.

If you know that this data won't change, for example, for next 2 minutes then you can implement some logic in `shouldReloadAll` which would prevent Ember from firing unnecessary request (like check if 2 minutes passed, if not then prevent request - `return false`).

See [`DS.Adapter.shouldReloadAll`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_shouldReloadAll) method documentation for more context.