# Trouble upgrading to Ember/Ember-Data 2.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have an ember-cli project, and I'm trying to get to ember 2.0. I know the idea is to remove all deprecation warning before upgrading, but I don't know what to do about this one:

```
DEPRECATION: The default behavior of shouldReloadAll will change in Ember Data 2.0 
to always return false when there is at least one "foo" record in the store. 
If you would like to preserve the current behavior please override shouldReloadAll 
in your adapter:application and return true. 
[deprecation id: ds.adapter.should-reload-all-default-behavior]
```

This warning is related to a call that I make for `this.store.findAll('foo')` for example.

As far as I can understand, fixing this would involve change the behavior of either `ember-data` or `ember-django-adapter`.

Here is my (partial) `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "ember-cli": "1.13.13",
    "ember-data": "1.13.15",
    "ember-django-adapter": "^1.1.1",
  }
}
```

Here is a some of my `bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.13.11",
    "ember-data": "1.13.15",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.20",
  }
}
```

So, after reading a bit, I thought maybe I can just ignore this warning, and maybe the behavior of `shouldReloadAll` isn't all that important for my app.

I'll list my steps carefully, because I'm not very familiar with npm or bower, and I may well be doing something wrong.

1. Change ember and ember-data to `"~2.0.0"` wherever they occur in `package.json` and `ember.json`
2. `npm uninstall ember-data`
3. `bower uninstall ember-data`
4. `bower uninstall ember`
5. `npm cache clear`
6. `bower cache clear`
7. `npm install`
8. `bower install`

At this point it is telling me that I have installed `ember-data@2.0.1` and `ember@2.0.2`

I then run the application, and find the following error:

```
TypeError: str.replace is not a function
    at Object.func (ember.debug.js:35278)
    at Object.Cache.get (ember.debug.js:12867)
    at decamelize (ember.debug.js:35320)
    at Object.func (ember.debug.js:35235)
    at Object.Cache.get (ember.debug.js:12867)
    at Object.dasherize (ember.debug.js:35324)
    at ember$data$lib$system$normalize$model$name$$normalizeModelName (normalize-model-name.js:13)
    at ember$data$lib$serializers$json$serializer$$default.extend.modelNameFromPayloadKey (rest-serializer.js:426)
    at ember$data$lib$serializers$json$serializer$$default.extend._normalizePolymorphicRecord (rest-serializer.js:161)
    at rest-serializer.js:141onerrorDefault @ ember.debug.js:29661exports.default.trigger @ ember.debug.js:51067(anonymous function) @ ember.debug.js:52059Queue.invoke @ ember.debug.js:978Queue.flush @ ember.debug.js:1042DeferredActionQueues.flush @ ember.debug.js:838Backburner.end @ ember.debug.js:166Backburner.run @ ember.debug.js:288run @ ember.debug.js:19125hash.success @ rest-adapter.js:735fire @ jquery.js:3148self.fireWith @ jquery.js:3260done @ jquery.js:9314callback @ jquery.js:9718
```

The following versions are reported:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
vendor.js:15777 DEBUG: Ember      : 2.0.2
vendor.js:15777 DEBUG: Ember Data : 2.0.1
vendor.js:15777 DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.3
vendor.js:15777 DEBUG: -------------------------------
vendor.js:19380 Rendering application with bracketfun-web@view:toplevel: Object
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** This error doesn't seem related to the deprecation, in any explanation of the deprecation that I've received.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DEPRECATION: The default behavior of shouldReloadAll will change in Ember Data 2.0 to always return false when there is at least one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016676/deprecation-the-default-behavior-of-shouldreloadall-will-change-in-ember-data-2)

Comment: Did you try just doing what it said? Simply override the `shouldReloadAll()` method in your application adapter (which will extend the Django adapter) and just make it return true. The reason for the change is so that results are cached, and can be explicitly reloaded using `this.store.findAll('foo', { reload: true })`.

Comment: @uberclops I guess I don't understand how to do that. I didn't think I had an _application adapter_. Could you explain to me how exactly I would override that method?

Comment: @uberclops I've now tried explicitly reloading, and still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your application adapter by using `ember generate drf-adapter application` from the command line. This should create the file `app/adapters/application.js`, to which you will add the override of `shouldReloadAll()`, and the end result should look something like this:

```
import DRFAdapter from './drf';

export default DRFAdapter.extend({
    shouldReloadAll() {
        return true;
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** `replace` error.

If you look at the stack trace and see where the error is coming from, you'll see it's originating from the serializer. It's struggling to get the model name from the payload. This is most likely due to the fact that you have not set up your application serializer.

You can generate the serializer using `ember generate drf-serializer application`. This will create the file `app/serializers/application.js`.

Remember Ember does not know to implicitly use an adapter / serializer by simply installing the add on, you need to tell it to use them by creating an application adapter and serializer.

Comment: This looks potentially useful. Can you tell me how you were able to learn this? Details like `drf-adapter` are things that couldn't be guessed by me, so I'm either missing a convention, or the right location in documentation.

Comment: @EricWilson this is the correct answer, IF you actually want shouldReloadAll to return true (i don't in my project).  shouldReloadAll is an Ember Data directive that informs ED if it should make subsequent calls to your API if there are already records in the store.  shouldReloadAll used to return true by default (API hit for every store.findAll request).  As of 2.0 it returns false by default (a single API hit on the first store.findAll request, then rely on the store cache going forward)—hence the "deprecation".  http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_shouldReloadAll

Comment: @dustinfarris I thought that was the idea of the deprecation, but it still puzzles me why it produced an error. Relying on the cache or not shouldn't produce an error with regarding `str.replace` related to `normalizeModelName` should it? Seems the worst I should expect would be out of date results, in certain scenarios, right?

Comment: @dustinfarris Didn't fix the actual error. I think I need to figure out how to return `'first-name'` instead of `'first_name'` (for example) from my API. But this is somewhat of a guess & I'm not sure the right way to do that.

Comment: @EricWilson If you look at the documentation for `ember-django-adapter` you'll find the command to generate the application adapter. Remember when working with Ember Data, the `application` adapter and serializer will be applied by convention to all models, unless you provide a specific implementation for a given model. As for the attribute naming, Ember provides plenty of hooks (such as `keyForAttribute`) to change the naming conventions used for serialization (go check the Ember Data RESTSerializer API documentation).

Comment: @uberclops This is killing me. No one will give me a clue why the `str.replace` errors. I've asked my question badly I realize, because I'm becoming convinced that there is no relationship between my error and the deprecation. I'll have to ask another question when I have time to better isolate the error.

Comment: @uberclops Thanks for your edit. I've now created a serializer, and I don't know what do with it. I'm pretty frustrated, this stuff "just worked" in ember 1.13.

Comment: @EricWilson You shouldn't have to do anything in the serializer unless you're doing something out of the ordinary. I think to continue this discussion (and get some additional help) it would be best to start a conversation on http://discuss.emberjs.com/.